# Snowflake COPY INTO Command return

Tags: amazon-s3, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a question about the snowflake `COPY INTO`, searched but did not get my answers.
Suppose I want to push data from snowflake to s3 bucket and using the snowflake `COPY INTO` command in my code, How will I know if the file is ready or command is completed? So that I can read the file from the s3 location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following things to check whether your COPY INTO was successful or at least to retrieve some useful information about your command:

- Set DETAILED_OUTPUT = TRUE and check the result (this means you get information about every single unloaded file as a output; if set to "false" you only receive information about the whole unload-process)
- Query your stage by using the syntax that can be found here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html
- Query the metadata of your staged data by using metadata$filename and metadata$file_row_number: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html

Keep in mind that even a failed COPY-command can result in some unloaded files on your stage.

More information can also be found at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#validating-data-to-be-unloaded-from-a-query

Comment: So if i am doing something COPY INTO `s3 location` with `DETAILED_OUTPUT = TRUE`, so it will keep loading until the file is uploaded into s3 and will give information about the file as output of the query?

Comment: Yes. It runs the COPY INTO-command and afterwards you get a output that has one row per unloaded file and information about the path, the file name, the file size and the number of rows of the file.

Regarding your sync-question: The query runs till it fails or succeeds and then you see the output mentioned above.

Comment: Hope my answer helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you're actually running this.

any Snowflake interface will run synchronously so the query will just spin until it's complete.

any async call would need extra checks - the easiest one being the web interface (it will show the status of the query and when it completes the unload is complete)

Comment: It will be in a scala code, I want to read from s3 file as soon as file is ready.